# inserting and deleting not happening in local database (.sdf)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sql-insert, sql-delete, local-database

When I try to select values from a local database it executes without any issue. But when I try to insert and delete it's executing the query but it's not affecting any rows.

This is the code I'm using to delete row from my local database:

```
        SqlCeConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlCeConnection();
        sqlConnection1.ConnectionString = "Data Source = Database1.sdf";

        SqlCeCommand cmd = sqlConnection1.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE slno=2";
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

        sqlConnection1.Open();
        cmd.Prepare();
        int aff=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//here its returning '0'
        MessageBox.Show(aff.ToString());
        sqlConnection1.Dispose();
        sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Comment: Could you try to handle the exception please? put your code in a try catch block and try to see what the exception is thrown, it might help to diagnose the issue.

Comment: silly question but are you sure you have a row in table1 with slno = 2?

Comment: Are you sure, that the data is really in the database? Are you sure, you are accessing the correct .sdf file? The problem could be that there is one in your project folder and one in bin\Debug.

Comment: ya with the same table i'm executed 'select' command it's working but for insert and delete it's not working

Comment: @AnarchistGeek : it's not giving any exception but it not executing delete

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the delete won't affect any rows.

As an aside, I would advise using the `using` statement in your code:

```
using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = Database1.sdf"))
using (SqlCeCommand comm = new SqlCeCommand("DELETE FROM table1 WHERE slno = 2", conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This will handle disposal of relevant objects for you.

Assuming that the SQL is relevant to your database and that you have successfully connected using the connection string beforehand, then the above could will perform a delete action against your database.

Comment: If you are basing that entirely on the returned rows I would suggest executing the same SQL in management studio to confirm that the delete itself does anything.